# Динамический парсинг строки в C#

Tags: c#

Есть строка вот такого типа:

```
Диагональ экрана: 32 ''; Соотношение сторон экрана: 16:9; Разрешение экрана: 1366x768; Технология экрана: ЖК; Частота обновления экрана: 50 Гц; TV-тюнер: DVB-T2, DVB-S2; Smart TV: есть; Мощность звука: 16 Вт; Разъемы вход и выход: HDMIx2, USBx2, Wi-Fi, Ethernet-LAN RJ-45, CI+, под наушники; Класс энергопотребления: A+; Поддержка 3D: нет; Цвет: черный; Крепление VESA: 100x100;
```

Нужно парсить строку по  ":" и первое значение заносить в одно поле класса, а второе - в другое. Окончанием является ";".

Каким образом можно это сделать?
Читал про split, но не понял как в цикле foreach распознать где первая половина строки, а где второе нужное значение.

Comment: Режете строку по `;`, затем в цикле обрабатываете полученные строки и каждую режете по `:`.

Comment: @XelaNimed в своем вопросе я указал что мне не совсем понятна такая реализация.

Comment: Функция Split возвращает массив. Когда вы разрежете ее первый раз, у вас будет массив из строк вида: `Диагональ экрана: 32`, `Разрешение экрана: 1366x768`, `Цвет: черный`. Пробежавшись по ним через foreach и сделав Split второй раз, вы получите массив из двух значение: result[0] и result[1] с правой и левой частью. P.S. за исключением строки `Соотношение сторон экрана: 16:9`, где будет три значения `result = ["Соотношение сторон экрана","16","9"];`

Answer (score 5):

```cs
string str = "...";
string[] semicolonPairs = str.Split(new char[]{';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
for(int i = 0; i < semicolonPairs.Length; i++) {
    string t = semicolonPairs[i].Trim();
    if(t.Length > 0){
        string[] pair = t.Split(new char[]{':'}, 2);
        Console.WriteLine("name: " + pair[0] + ", value: " + pair[1]);
    }
}
```

Можете "поиграться" [здесь](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ua1h78).

---

Аналог на JS.

```js
var str = "Диагональ экрана: 32 ''; Соотношение сторон экрана: 16:9; Разрешение экрана: 1366x768; Технология экрана: ЖК; Частота обновления экрана: 50 Гц; TV-тюнер: DVB-T2, DVB-S2; Smart TV: есть; Мощность звука: 16 Вт; Разъемы вход и выход: HDMIx2, USBx2, Wi-Fi, Ethernet-LAN RJ-45, CI+, под наушники; Класс энергопотребления: A+; Поддержка 3D: нет; Цвет: черный; Крепление VESA: 100x100;";

var semiColonPairs = str.split(";");
for(var i = 0, sep = ":"; i < semiColonPairs.length; i++) {
  var pair = semiColonPairs[i].split(sep);
  if(pair.length > 1){
    var name = pair.shift().trim();
    var value = pair.join(sep).trim();
    console.log("%o = %o", name, value);
  }
}
```

Comment: вот это `16:9` тоже порежется?

Comment: @tym32167 теперь нет... Вернее "да", но если разрезало, то потом "склеется"...

Comment: А есть какой-нибудь аналог shift/join в .NET?

Comment: @PavelBihel на сколько я знаю "нет", но Вы можете получать доступ по индексу.

Comment: В .NET метод `Split` вторым параметром может принимать количество возвращаемых подстрок. Просто укажите его: `Split(sep, 2)`. И тогда 16:9 не порежется.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, не знал об этом параметре. Поправил ответ.